# Is there any way to improve the performance of the below code?

Tags: java

The codes is comparing 2 `list` of codes.First `list` is got from api call and second from database.I am using 2 loops to iterate over the list and compare them ,and add the common to a new list.The first list contains around 800 data and second list(from db) contains 150 data.Is there any way to improve the performance of this code.I am not allowed to make any changes in `AllowedCodes Class`.Does using nested loops affect performance with the given amount of data?

```
public class AllowedCodes {

    private String codeValue="";

    public String getCodeValue() {
        return codeValue;
    }

    public void setCodeValue(String codeValue) {
        this.codeValue = codeValue;
    }
}

public class CheckCodes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<AllowedCodes> old_codes_list=getListOfOldCodes();

        List<AllowedCodes> new_codes_list=new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "This query gets the codes from database";

        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()) {

            for(AllowedCodes a:old_codes){
               if(a.getCodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase(result.getCodeValue())){
                   new_codes_list.add(a);
               }
            }

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Use a `HashSet` instead of a list for `old_codes_list`. (Store and compare codes as lower case to ignore the original casing.)

Comment: It has to be an ArrayList.Thats what the response i get from api call.And there are no duplicates.Is there any way to decrease time complexity?

Comment: "Thats what the response i get from api call." copy it into a `HashSet`. Or some other data structure, like a Trie.

Comment: Wont that  cause increase in time? Even with the set i will have to do the same operations,i guess

Comment: The copying will cost you some, but you can then replace the linear `for` loop with a `set.contains(...)` which runs in constant time (amortized). (You'll do 1 linear operation, instead of hundreds.)

Comment: the `conatins()` method ,how does it work internally? because i have to compare user defined Class `AllowedCodes` .I guess contains() uses `equals()` or `compareTo()`.

Comment: Why does the database query return items with duplicate codes?

Comment: It does not return duplicates.There are no duplicates in both list

Comment: @LoneWolf: There are plenty of articles on [how HashMap works](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/). It involves grouping items based on a modulus of their `getHashCode()` value, so it doesn't have to call `equals()` on every item in the collection. You probably don't need to worry about the implementation details, though, so much as the fact that `contains()` is a `O(1)` operation, so creating a Map and checking all the items becomes a `O(n)`-complexity operation instead of `O(n²)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the list into a `HashMap`, grouping `AllowedCodes` that have the same code value when lowercased:

```
Map<String, List<AllowedCodes>> map =
    old_codes.stream().collect(groupingBy(a -> a.getCodeValue().toLowerCase()));
```

Then, in your while loop:

```
while(result.next()) {
  String resultCodeValue = result.getCodeValue().toLowerCase();
  for (AllowedCodes a : map.getOrDefault(resultCodeValue, Collections.emptyList())) {
    new_codes_list.add(a);
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try using steam api ,never used it before.Thanks Andy

Comment: You could use the stream api to avoid the while loop entirely, right? Just have a one-liner that creates the list after a `.filter(...contains(...))`?

Comment: will it work with a resultSet? Please provide a code.I will try using it.I am new to stream api.

Comment: @LoneWolf this uses the code your question shows: "`result.getCodeValue()`".

Comment: Yes @Andy , your code helps a lot.I was referring to StriplingWarrior ,whether the code he says works.